# Error FOREIGN KEY constraint while running Store Procedure while inserting NEWID() ID's run time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Created Tables**

```
create table Empl(E_ID nvarchar(36) primary key, Name varchar(50), Designation varchar(50)) 

create table Location(L_ID nvarchar(36) primary key, Location varchar(50), E_ID nvarchar(36) foreign key references Empl(E_ID)) 

create table Contact_Emp (C_ID nvarchar(36) primary key, Contact_Number varchar(50), Lo_ID nvarchar(36) foreign key references Location(L_ID))
```

**Store Procedure**

```
alter proc InsertMultiplevalue  
(  
@Name varchar(50),  
@Designation varchar(50),  
@Location varchar(50),  
@Contact varchar(50)  
)  
as  
begin  
        insert into Empl values(newid(),@Name, @Designation)  
        declare @Employee_ID nvarchar(36) = NEWID()  
        insert into Location values(@Location,@Employee_ID)  
        declare @Cot_ID nvarchar(36) = NEWID()  
        insert into Contact_Emp values(@Contact,@Cot_ID)  
end
```

Ececute SP

```
exec InsertMultiplevalue 'UserName','Programmer','India','Admin@learn2Free.Com'
```

I am getting this error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure InsertMultiplevalue, Line 25
>       The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Location__E_ID__33D4B598". The conflict occurred in database
>   "LocalDBTest", table "dbo.Empl", column 'E_ID'.
>       The statement has been terminated.
>       Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure InsertMultiplevalue, Line 27
>       The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Contact_E__Lo_ID__36B12243". The conflict occurred in database
>   "LocalDBTest", table "dbo.Location", column 'L_ID'.

Comment: You should also get another error, as number of columns matching in `insert` statement for location and contact Id values not supplied. Why cant u use `uniqueidentifier` data type

Comment: @Ven Yes, I got the solution posted in answer thanks for the reply

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using Nvarchar(36) datatype for `Newid()`

Comment: @Ven so which one I use for this

Comment: use Datatype `Uniqueidentifier` and if u  can also set a default for that as Newid(), so that you don't need to declare id's

Comment: @Ven thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changes in STore procedure it works

```
alter proc InsertMultiplevalue  
(  
@Name varchar(50),  
@Designation varchar(50),  
@Location varchar(50),  
@Contact varchar(50)  
)  
as  
begin  
          declare @Employee_ID nvarchar(36) = NEWID()  
        insert into Empl values(@Employee_ID,@Name, @Designation)  

        declare @Location_ID nvarchar(36) = NEWID() 
        insert into Location values(@Location_ID,@Location,@Employee_ID)  

        declare @Cot_ID nvarchar(36) = NEWID()  
        insert into Contact_Emp values(@Cot_ID,@Contact,@Location_ID)  
end
```